# Double Tap Gesture with NavigationLink produce random stack of DetailView

Tags: swiftui

I have a very weird issue with my double-tap gesture. I don't know this is a bug or my codes are wrong. Here, I want to use the Double Tap Gesture to open my DetailView by using NavigationLink. The problem is the page of my DetailView shows randomly which is supposed to match with the page of my SourceView. If I use a regular NavigationLink without using .onTapGesture, the seletected pages are matched. I couldn't find any solution online, but I found there are some bugs in NavigationLink. My codes examples are below. Please let me know if you have the same issue in using both onTapGesture and NavigationLink.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let cities: String
    var name1: String?
    var name2: String?
    var name3: String?
    var name4: String?
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static var dot = [
    DataArray(number: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "John",
        name2: "Mike"),
        
    DataArray(number: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        
    DataArray(number: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Susan",
        name2: "Oliver",
        name3: "Jude",
        name4: "Erik"),
            
    ]
}

struct Home: View {
    
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot
    @State var isDoubleTab: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (datas, id: \.id) { data in
                
                    HomeView(data: data)
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                            self.isDoubleTapped.toggle()
                        }
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(data: data),
                        isActivate: $isDoubleTab) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                        .padding()
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var data = DataArray
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStact {
            Text(data.cities)
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var data: DataArray
    var body: some View {
    
        VStack {
            HSTack {
                Text(data.cities).padding()
                
                Text(data.name1)
                
                if let sur2 = data.name2 {
                    surName2 = sur
                    
                    Text(surName2)
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
}
```

The above examples are closely matched my current code. For simplicity, I just shortened some duplicate names including padding() etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the [`init(_:destination:isActive:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:destination:isactive:)-3v44) version of ​`NavigationLink` inside
a `ForEach`. When you set `isDoubleTab` to true, **all** of the visible `NavigationLink`s will attempt to present. This will result in the unexpected behavior that you're seeing.

Instead, you'll need to use a different version of `NavigationLink`: [`init(_:destination:tag:selection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:destination:tag:selection:)-6unyq). But first, replace `@State var isDoubleTab: Bool = false` with a property that *stores* a `DataArray` — something like `@State var selectedData: DataArray?`.

```
@State var selectedData: DataArray? /// here!

...

.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
    /// set `selectedData` to the current loop iteration's `data`
    /// this will trigger the `NavigationLink`.
    selectedData = data
}
```

Then, replace your old `NavigationLink(_:destination:isActive:)` with this alternate version — instead of presenting once a `Bool` is set to `true`, it will present when `tag` matches `selectedData`.

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: DetailView(data: data),
    tag: data, /// will be presented when `tag` == `selectedData`
    selection: $selectedData
) {
    EmptyView()
}
```

Note that this also requires `data`, a `DataArray`, to conform to `Hashable`. That's as simple as adding it inside the struct definition.

```
struct DataArray: Identifiable, Hashable {
```

Result:

[image: Detail view's data is presented correctly]

Full code:

```
struct Home: View {
    
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot
    
//    @State var isDoubleTab: Bool = false // remove this
    @State var selectedData: DataArray? /// replace with this
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(datas, id: \.id) { data in
                    
                    HomeView(data: data)
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                            selectedData = data
                        }
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DetailView(data: data),
                        tag: data, /// will be presented when `data` == `selectedData`
                        selection: $selectedData
                    ) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                        .padding()
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}



struct DetailView: View {
    var data: DataArray
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(data.cities)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var data: DataArray
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(data.cities).padding()
                Text(data.name1 ?? "")
                
                /// not sure what this is for, doesn't seem related to your problem though so I commented it out
//                if let sur2 = data.name2 {
//                    surName2 = sur
//                    Text(surName2)
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static var dot = [
        DataArray(
            number: 1,
            cities: "Baltimore",
            name1: "John",
            name2: "Mike"
        ),
        DataArray(
            number: 2,
            cities: "Frederick"
        ),
        DataArray(
            number: 3,
            cities: "Catonsville",
            name1: "Susan",
            name2: "Oliver",
            name3: "Jude",
            name4: "Erik"
        )
    ]
}

struct DataArray: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let cities: String
    var name1: String?
    var name2: String?
    var name3: String?
    var name4: String?
}
```

Other notes:

- Your original code has a couple syntax errors and doesn't compile.
- You should rename `DataArray` to just `Data`, since it's a struct and not an array.

Comment: @Lian sorry, I don't use hangouts. Maybe just ask another question here?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Which one is a better approach to use struct or class to create Data like the above example? The reason is my data in DataArray are very long. Let's say it is about over 700. I found some delay every time I load or refresh my data.